# Calling a jQuery function inside html return from an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a web page that is using jQuery. I have an Ajax call that gets data from the server and updates a div. Inside that data there is a jQuery function, but the function is not being called after the data is loaded into the page. I have the proper js files included in the page already.

This is what is returned from the Ajax call and placed into a div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
         $('input').myFunction('param');             
    }); 
</script>
<p> other html </p>
```

How do I get the returned javascript to run after the html is inserted into the page?

(I am using Rails with the jRails plugin )

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want JavaScript tag evaluation, with html content, you should set the dataType option of the ajax call to "html":

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "yourPage.htm",
  dataType: "html"
});
```

Or dataType "script", if you want to load and execute a .js file:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  dataType: "script"
});
```

more info here: [Ajax/jQuery.ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options)

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to add little jquery date pickers to a couple fields I was retrieving via ajax.  here is what I did to get around it... just quick and dirty. Instead of returning this whole block from my ajax call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
         $('input').myFunction('param');                         
    }); 
</script>
<p> other html </p>
```

I would return this (note the made up |x| separator)

```
    $(function() {
         $('input').myFunction('param');                         
    }); 

|x|

<p> other html </p>
```

Then when I received the data back via ajax, I split the return value into 2 parts: the javascript to be executed, and the html to display:

```
 r = returnvalfromajax.split("|x|");       
 document.getElementById('whatever').innerHTML = r[1];  
 eval(r[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
</script>
```

To:

```
<script>
...
</script>
```

Fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can use jQuery load() function: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback
As a callback you can define function which will be executed after loading new content
example:

$("#feeds").load("new_content.html",, doSomething());

and in new_content.html you can define function doSomething()...

Answer (score -1):

for ajax.net the `endRequestHandler(sender, args)` solution works fine though

Answer (score -7):

have you tried Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.add_endRequest method?

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler);           
    }
    );
    function endRequestHandler(sender, args)
    {
        // whatever
    }
```