# Using infinite scrolling to load more content and extend the page?

Tags: php, database, dynamic

I am trying to use infinite scrolling to load the next 5 peices of content onto my screen without reloading the entire page. I have tried about a million things. I have the scroll bar tracking working great, but I have no idea how to set up an ajax request to load additional content when the scroll bar script is activated. Please help I have been stuck on this for two days.

here is my java script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function yHandler(){
var wrap = document.getElementById('wrap');
var contentHeight = wrap.offsetHeight;
var yOffset = window.pageYOffset; 
var y = yOffset + window.innerHeight;
if(y >= contentHeight){
    // Ajax call to get more dynamic data goes here
    wrap.innerHTML += '<div class="newData"></div>';
}
var status = document.getElementById('status');
status.innerHTML = contentHeight+" | "+y;
}

window.onscroll = yHandler;
</script>
```

here is my php file to connect to my database:

```
    <?php

    # FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
    # Type="MYSQL"
    # HTTP="true"
    $hostname_dbConn = "localhost";
    $database_dbConn = "Video";
    $username_dbConn = "root";
    $password_dbConn = "root";
    $dbConn = mysql_pconnect($hostname_dbConn, $username_dbConn, $password_dbConn) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 

    ?>
```

Comment: This is too broad to answer as one question

Comment: How can I narrow it down?

Comment: Ask how to do ajax calls to begin....then ask how to do pagination queries with ajax, then marry the too, and you have infinite scrolling

Comment: Although,...this page might clear things up for you a bit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164767/infinite-scrolling-within-ajax-loaded-page?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: As noted by other commenters, put together a better picture with the individual pieces, but this should at least get you on the right track.

The question is very broad but for the AJAX bit use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)!
Simplest thing I can think of without getting into too many details.

### JS

```
var last_grabbed = 5;
function scrollListen() {
    ...
    $.post('path/to/script.php',{ 'last_row' : last_grabbed },function(response) {
        $('.my-content-div').append(response);
        last_grabbed += 5;
    });
}
```

### PHP

```
<?php
//your connection stuff, db select, etc
$row = $_POST['last_row']; //you should sanitize this though
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT ... LIMIT $row,5") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
?>
<!-- Do you HTML stuff here for each item !-->
<?php
}
?>
```

That should get you started. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp for more on the PHP side.

Comment: Thank you. As you can see I was not even remotely sure how to get started. This helps a lot.